# Dun & Bradstreet integration

Tags: integration

We are implementing Salesforce for a customer whose customers are other businesses.B2B. We are thinking of integrating with Dun & Bradstreet. When sales reps create accounts, we want to give them a list of matching records from D&B so that they can enter good quality data in the system. Does anyone have experience in integrating with D&B in real time or may be batch mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Data.com](http://www.data.com/), which is a Salesforce product set up in partnership with D&B. It should do what you are looking for and is completely integrated out-of-the-box.